# What is using swap. Python version

Tags: python, linux, memory, swap

I already have a shell script that can determine which process is using swap and how much, but I would rather do this in python.

Shell one-liner (I found this script on the web but can't remember it's origin):

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done| sort -k 2 -n
```

The script above basically looks through /proc and gets process name, PID and how much swap space it's using.

As far as python is concerned memory_maps() from [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) looks promising, but I can't find where the output specifies process name or PID.

What am I trying to do?  I'm trying to rewrite a bunch of old shell scripts that collect things like CPU, memory, swap, usage etc into one big python program.  I know that I can call these scripts using subprocess or shellexec, but I want to avoid that as much as possible.

What am I asking?  Is there a better way to do this? Is my approach all wrong?

Edit:

I have made some progress with python3. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import glob

class searchfile:
    def __init__(self, file, searchstring1, searchstring2, searchstring3, searchstring4 ):
        self.file = file
        self.searchstring1 = searchstring1
        self.searchstring2 = searchstring2
        self.searchstring3 = searchstring3
        self.searchstring4 = searchstring4

class searchparm(searchfile):
    def printsearch(self):
        hand = open(self.file)
        for line in hand:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if re.search(self.searchstring1, line):
                print (line)
            if re.search(self.searchstring2, line):
                print (line)
            if re.search(self.searchstring3, line):
                print (line)
            if re.search(self.searchstring4, line):
                print (line)


for file in glob.glob('/proc/*/status'):
    search_proc = searchparm(file, 'Name', 'VmSwap', 'Pid:', 'VmSize:' )
    print("#########################################")
    print("#########################################")
    print(search_proc.printsearch())
```

Comment: You can read `/proc/<pid>/status` from Python.

Answer (score 1):

`memory_maps()` in psutil is only a function to memory map the specified process (not for every process).

Let's start from the beginning - psutil provides a `pids()` method that lists all the processes currently running, and you then have to create a `Process` object that lets you access memory and other metrics about that particular process. So for example, you could write `print psutil.Process().memory_maps()` to get the memory map for the current Python process (it defaults to the running process if no PID is given).

Here's an example of how you could get the same swap data as with your shell script with `psutil` (note that you'll need to run Python as root to get info on system processes):

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():  # quicker way to iterate
    print p.pid, p.name(), p.memory_full_info().swap
```

Sample output:

```
...
669 kvm-irqfd-clean 0
731 systemd-timesyncd 475136
827 rpcbind 901120
837 ModemManager 3784704
846 thermald 983040
851 cron 409600
854 systemd-logind 647168
855 acpid 327680
859 avahi-daemon 413696
860 dbus-daemon 2416640
873 avahi-daemon 569344
879 NetworkManager 3088384
...
```

The full documentation is in the [Process](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class) class for psutil.